# Correct way to create CollectionView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

When using storyboards or nibs, outlets for CollectionViews are implicitly unwrapped, so accessing and configuring the collectionView is a straightforward process.

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

When creating them programmatically we can do something like this:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Would this be the correct approach? Theres no guarantee that the collectionView will be initialised, so there's always the possibility for a crash. I would also like to avoid having an optional since I will be forced to unwrap it every time.

Answer (score 3):

I always create them as computed, as there are some attributes you want to add to it. And often `lazy` as well so you can set `dataSource` and `delegate`. You also wants to add the `collectionViewLayout` in it's initializer. Hence i'm creating the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` first.

```
private lazy var selectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 64, height: 24)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 64, height: 24)
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 12
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
        return collectionView
    }()
```

Comment: Do you also take the same approach when creating something like an ImageView or a UIButton?

Comment: Yes i do, the lazy attribute means that it defer's the creation till the viewcontroller is initiated and i can therefor set all the views attributes in one place

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewController = MyCollectionViewController()
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(viewController, animated: true) {}
    }
}
```

MyCollectionViewController.swift

```
    import UIKit

    class MyCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
        var dataModels: [DataModel?] = [DataModel]()
        private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            collectionView.delegate = self
            collectionView.dataSource = self
            collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
            collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
            return collectionView
        }()

        override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
            super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        init() {
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
            self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow

            let data = (0...10).map { value -> DataModel in
                DataModel(name: "\(value)")
            }
            dataModels.append(contentsOf: data)
            addCollectionView()
        }

        func addCollectionView() {
            self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView)
            self.collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }



    extension MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
                if let dataModel = dataModels[indexPath.row] {
                    print(">>>>\(dataModel.name)")
                    cell.nameLabel.text = dataModel.name
                }
                return cell
            }
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.dataModels.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
            return CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
    extension MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        }
    }


    class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        var storeBack = UIView()
        var nameLabel = UILabel()

        public override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            commonInit()
        }

        public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            commonInit()
        }

        fileprivate func commonInit() {
            self.contentView.addSubview(self.storeBack)
            self.storeBack.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
            self.storeBack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.storeBack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.storeBack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.storeBack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.storeBack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

            self.storeBack.addSubview(self.nameLabel)
            self.nameLabel.textColor = .black
            self.nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
            self.nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

            self.nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: storeBack.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: storeBack.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: storeBack.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: storeBack.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }

    struct DataModel: Codable {
        var name: String
    }
```